# Can I join two tables in MYSQL and create a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a new table after joining this two tables if it is possible

```
SELECT * FROM tablepeople
JOIN tableinfo
ON tablepeople.id = tableinfo.ctrlid
```

Comment: do you need an actual real table, or would a view do instead? the real table wouldn't stay synched with the original tables, while the view would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) construct like below; considering the fact that the `new_table` doesn't already exists

```
create table new_table as
SELECT * from tablepeople 
join tableinfo 
on tablepeople.id = tableinfo.ctrlid
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the latest comment, use a table alias to get around this

```
CREATE TABLE mytable3 AS
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM mytable1 t1
    JOIN mytable2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: this is not working when two tables have same id column names

Comment: @IsaacSim There is no reason why it wouldn't work. Please post a separate question with all details and can help

Comment: I second @IsaacSim comment. [Refer this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=709ad4079e45acf548123039e8dd6e4a)

Comment: @FanoFN See edit in answer .. essentially you need to use a table alias to get around this

Answer (score 0):

**you can use**

**Create table new_table**

```
Create table new_table as
SELECT * FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.idcustomers = orders.idorders
UNION
SELECT * FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN orders ON customers.idcustomers = orders.idorders;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will join two table and create the new table with that two joined table

```
Syntex: select * into new_table_name
From table1 as t1
Join table2 as t2 ON t2.column name = 
t1.column name;



Example: select * into emp_detls
From employee as emp
Join employeeDOB AS edob ON edob.employeeID 
= emp.e_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [table_name] ( [query] );
```

OR

```html
CREATE TABLE [table_name] ( [query] );
```